# Get all nodes of given type

Tags: nodes, 8

I would like to get all nodes that are of `my_custom_type` type **in Drupal 8**.

I know I can get all the nodes (of any type) with [`\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AloadMultiple/8.2.x) and the list of all types by `\Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple()`.

But **how to get only the nodes of given node type?**

I really don't want to use specialized module for it (if it's possible), just keep it as simple as possible. I will use the solution in my custom module.

And loading all the nodes with `\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple()` and then check their type in `foreach` would hit the performance too much.

Comment: What do you mean filter by name? Why not build a Views page for that through the interface? It will construct the query for you, and you can add a filter where users can enter text to search.

Comment: Because i want it inside a method, so can  get them all without filter? i do filter later

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use [`Drupal::entityQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x) & `Node::loadMultiple()` to load all the nodes of your given type:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','my_custom_type')->execute();
$nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

Comment: Any way to do this generically for any entity type? You would think \Drupal::entityQuery($type)->condition('type',$bundle)>execute(); would work, but sadly no.

Comment: This answer is specific to node entities. Details will change for other entities. You should ask another question for a general case.

Comment: In OOP code this now is `$nids = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery()->condition('type','my_custom_type')->execute();`. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874.

Comment: Be careful if you send a null value to Node::loadMultiple() it will load all nodes, add a if ( is_array($nids) ) or if( $nids)  to check the values of $nids

Comment: Just to say it clearly, this answer is deprecated. Read comment from @leymannx above, this is the right way now.

Comment: @wranvaud – It depends where you gonna use this code. For an update hook for example the entity query is perfectly fine. For OOP code, inject the entity type manager. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874.

Answer (score 31):

Another way to do this would be using this snippet of code:

```
// Set properties to filter.
$values = [
  'type' => 'page',
];

// Get the nodes.
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties($values);
```

Answer (score 20):

Its actually very easy,

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['type' => 'content_type', 'status' => 1])
```

If you would like all nodes also unpublished just use:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['type' => 'content_type'])
```

Comment: This method is the best option, because LoadMultiple can cause side effect (check my comment in first solution).

Answer (score 8):

Usually you need published nodes, not all.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'YOUR-NODE-TYPE')
  ->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use entity storage.

```
$storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
```

There are two main ways to query for entities:

1. Using entity storage's [getQuery()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AgetQuery/8.9.x) method

```
$my_entity_ids = $storage->getQuery()
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute();

$my_entities = $storage->loadMultiple($my_entity_ids);
```

2. Using entity_storage's [loadByProperties()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.9.x) method

```
$my_entities = $storage->loadByProperties([
  'type' => 'article',
  'status' => 1,
]);
```

Either one is perfectly acceptable and just use whichever makes more sense in your situation.

Additionally, since it looks like you're doing this in a class of some sort, you can use Dependency Injection to inject the *entity_type.manager* service. This is well documented in this related post: [How to inject a service in another service?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248157/how-to-inject-a-service-in-another-service)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109933/discussion-between-sonfd-and-david-montera).

Answer (score 0):

Something that was, at one time, fairly simple to figure out and find documentation for has become quite a bit more confusing and hard to find. This is one of the top search results for this topic, so I want to take the time to post a solution I was able to put together using the new Methods.

My use case is getting a list of published nodes of a certain content type and publishing them to a page as XML to be consumed by a third party.

Here are my declarations. Some of them might be superfluous at this point, but I'm not done upgrading the code as of yet.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_events_feed\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Component\Serialization;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager;
```

Here's the code to just feed the object into the XML

```
/**
 * Class BuildXmlController.
 */
class BuildXmlController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Builds the xml from an object
   */
  public function build() {
    $my_events = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'status' => '1',
      'type' => 'submit_an_event',
    ]);

    $thisSerializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $serializedData = $thisSerializer->serialize($my_events, 'xml', ['plugin_id' => 'entity']);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    $response->setContent($serializedData);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

If you need to massage the data, then you'll have to fill an array and make edits there. Of course, you can still serialize a standard library array.

```
/**
 * Class BuildXmlController.
 */
class BuildXmlController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Builds the xml from an array
   */
  public function build() {

    $my_events = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'status' => '1',
      'type' => 'submit_an_event',
    ]);

    $nodedata = [];
    if ($my_events) {
      /*
      Get the details of each node and
      put it in an array.
      We have to do this because we need to manipulate the array so that it will spit out exactly the XML we want
       */
      foreach ($my_events as $node) {
        $nodedata[] = $node->toArray();
      }
    }

    foreach ($nodedata as &$nodedata_row) {
      /* LOGIC TO MESS WITH THE ARRAY GOES HERE */
    }

    $thisSerializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $serializedData = $thisSerializer->serialize($nodedata, 'xml', ['plugin_id' => 'entity']);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    $response->setContent($serializedData);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 9.2 onwards, now requires **Access checking** to be explicitly specified on content entity queries

```
// This will trigger a deprecation error.
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->execute();

// Unchanged: This gets all articles the current user can view.
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->accessCheck(TRUE)
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->execute();

// Unchanged: This gets all articles that exist regardless of access.
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->execute();
```

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/3201242