# How to inject a service in another service?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

I am building a custom service, a membership service.
This service can be called from a controller.
But what I don't seem to get working, is to use another service, the QueryFactory, to use in that custom service.

the membership service:

```
namespace Drupal\hsbxl_members;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Class MembershipService.
 */
class MembershipService {
  protected $hsbxl_member;
  protected $entityQuery;

  public function __construct(QueryFactory $entityQuery) {
    $this->entity_query = $entity_query;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity.query')
    );
  }

  public function MembershipsAll() {
    $query = $this->entity_query->get('node');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $nids = $query->execute();
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

services file:

```
services:
  hsbxl_members.membership:
    class: Drupal\hsbxl_members\MembershipService
    arguments: ['@entity.query']
```

Can anyone point me out on this?
What am I doing wrong / am I missing?

Tom

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Comment: Couple of things: it’s entity_type.query (the other one is deprecated), and you don’t need the create() method as it’s a service and injection happens a different way. Not sure either of those are causing the problem but worth a look

Comment: Clive beat me to it. You don't need the create method. The constructor will receive the arguments from the services.yml definition. Other than that if you can list the error that would help.

Comment: Some constructive advice, you may want to think about method names. Ex. instead of MembershipsAll, make it getAllMemberships, or getMemberships($filter_args).

Comment: Thanks for your help all.
The error get is
    Error: Call to a member function get() on null in Drupal\hsbxl_members\MembershipService->getMemberships()

Comment: So $this->entity_query is null

Comment: Did you update the name of the service as Clive said, the one you are fetching from the container?

Comment: Also your protected member declaration does not match the one you set in the constructor. Update that. Pass `$entity_query` into the constructor, but set `$this->entityQuery =`...

Comment: OK, got it working. Indeed, I was using $entityquery instead of $entity_query. But about changing the service, where do I change this? I am not following. Do I need to change the 'use Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory'? entity_type.query where?

Comment: Actually your service file looks fine. I got mixed up looking at the create statement which should not be there. One last thing, your constructor argument should pass QueryInterface and not QueryFactory. As long as the incoming object implements this interface, your code will be adaptable. Check out the SOLID principle.

Comment: Sorry @betz I misled you a bit there, it's `entity_type.manager` not `entity_type.query`. I added an answer with an example

Answer (score 7):

The service you need is [`entity_type.manager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_type.manager/8.4.x):

.services.yml

```
services:
  hsbxl_members.membership:
    class: Drupal\hsbxl_members\MembershipService
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
```

MembershipService.php

```
namespace Drupal\hsbxl_members;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class MembershipService.
 */
class MembershipService {
  protected $hsbxl_member;
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  public function MembershipsAll() {
    $query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $nids = $query->execute();
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

The `create()` method is unnecessary as services use [constructor injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection).

Comment: Why did you use `EntityTypeManagerInterface` rather than using `EntityTypeManager` directly?

Comment: Do you mean for the type hint @Kevin? It doesn’t make sense to use a concrete class when an interface is available, it would mean your code is less flexible/testable